# Use width of certain block of text as parameter

Tags: macros, conditionals, width, ifthenelse, textwidth

I wonder if it's possible to get the width of a certain block of text, passed as an argument in `\newcommand` and use it numerically inside a conditional.

For example, defining a `\newcommand` which prints the text (passed as an argument) in red if its width is greater than 6cm, and blue in other case.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{calc}

\newcommand{\tc}[1]{
\ifthenelse{ \convertto{cm}{ \textwidth{#1} } > 6 }{\textcolor{red}{#1}}{\textcolor{blue}{#1}}
}

\begin{document}
\tc{hello}
\end{document}
```

but `\textwidth` doesn't return a numerical value, or I'm not using it in a correct way.

Comment: The `\textwidth` command does not take an argument and simply returns the width of the text block, so you're trying to convert `345pthello` to cm (`345pt` is the value of `\textwidth`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here, I set the text in a temporary box0, and compare, via `\ifdim`, the width of that box to `6cm`.  I decide the color based on the outcome of that test.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcommand{\tc}[1]{%
  \sbox0{#1}%
  \ifdim\wd0>6cm\relax\textcolor{red}{#1}\else\textcolor{blue}{#1}\fi
}

\begin{document}
\tc{hello}

\tc{This is a test of very long text to see if it goes red}
\end{document}
```

[image]